# Laravel validation: unique rule to bring duplicated record back

Tags: mysql, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have not found anywhere a clean way of what I am exactly looking for so thought to give on here a try:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'an_id' => 'unique:users,an_id',
            'another_id' => 'unique:users,another_id',
            'test_id' => 'unique:users,test_id',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            //
        }
```

So, what I'd like to do is when a duplicate `test_id` is provided, is to not only fail but show me which user uses the same `test_id`.

Is this actually possible through Laravel's Validation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, is this what you want to achieve?

Update: maybe you want to get the duplicated user in the view.

Update2: a quick way to get and return the duplicated users, if any.

(Note: I haven't tested the code so maybe slight adjustments are needed)

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'an_id' => 'unique:users,an_id',
    'another_id' => 'unique:users,another_id', 
    'test_id' => 'unique:users,test_id',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {

    //find the duplicated user
    $duplicatedUserX = User::where(
       'another_id', $request->input('another_id')
    )->get();

    $duplicatedUserY = User::where(
        'test_id', $request->input('test_id')
    )->get();

    // add their test_id to error messagebag.
    if(!empty($duplicatedUserX){
        $validator->errors()
            ->add('duplicatedUserXId', $duplicatedUserX->id);
    }

    if(!empty($duplicatedUserY){
        $validator->errors()
            ->add('duplicatedUserYId', $duplicatedUserY->id);
    }

    // Send duplicated users and messagebag back to View
    return redirect()->back()
      ->with('dupUsers', [
        'x' => $duplicatedUserX,
        'y' => $duplicatedUserY,
      ])->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @hktang!

What if it's the `another_id ` failing?

Comment: @thitami, hope it helped! My idea is you can assign $dupUserForAnotherID and $dupUserForTestID and send both to the view. Note, it can be null value. Then you can retrieve it on the View. I hope there are more elegant ways to do this though.